# How to limit the number of group in a user in Django-Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been searching for an answer to this all over and I can't seem to find it. I created a user in Django admin and I want to limit the number of group that can be added to it. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a `pre_save` signal handler that checks how many groups the user has been added to already and raises an error if it exceeds your limit.

Documentation on how to create signal handlers is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/